# Парсинг цен и названий товара с озона

Tags: парсер

всем!
Попытался написать парсер цены и названия товара для получения данных с озона
Проблема заключается в том, что парсится только 4 позиции со страницы
Причем из непонятного мне места
Как сделать так, чтобы страница парсилась полностью?

Код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Link = 'https://www.ozon.ru/seller/magika-191127/products/?page=29'

HEADERS = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 YaBrowser/21.8.3.614 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36', 'accept': '*/*'}

def get_html(url,params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    cards = soup.find_all('div', class_='bh6 bi')

    data_prices = []
    data_names = []

    for card in cards:
        data_prices.append(card.find('span', class_='ui-p5 ui-p8 ui-q0').get_text())
        data_names.append(card.find('span', class_='a7y a8a2 a8a6 a8b2 f-tsBodyL bj5').get_text())

    print(data_prices)
    print(data_names)

def parse(url):

    html = get_html(url)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_content(html.text)
    else:
        print('Error')

parse(Link)
```

Выводит следующее:
['3\u2009740\u2009₽', '4\u2009085\u2009₽', '4\u2009100\u2009₽', '3\u2009730\u2009₽']

['Настольная лампа-светильник "Корона в винограде "', 'Настольная лампа-светильник "Мэри"', 'Настольная лампа-светильник "Галактика-бутон"', 'Настольная лампа-светильник "Золотой кубок " на ножке бежевого цвета']